# ¿Como rediccionar a Facebook y a Google Maps? Dart y flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo que rediccionar a Facebook y a Google Maps (de ambos tengo, para el caso de Facebook la url del perfil que se quiere ir. y de Google Maps las coordenadas x, y).

Tengo el siguiente Row de Icons:

Con el código:

```
class fila_botones extends StatelessWidget {
  String celular,facebook,x,y;
  fila_botones(this.celular,this.facebook,this.x,this.y);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final barraiconos = Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20.0,
        left: 20.0,
        right: 20.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Tooltip(
                 child: Icon(
                 Icons.call,
                  size: 50.0,
                  ),
              message: 'El celu es: ' + celular.toString()),

              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50.0,
                left: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              _launchURL();
            }
          ),



          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.facebookSquare,  //FAVORITOS EN CRHOME
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
//ACA IRIA EL REDICCIONAMIENTO A FACEBOOK DONDE TENGO EN EL STRING FACEBOOK TENGO LA URL
            }
            ,
          ),
          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.mapMarkedAlt,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
//ACA IRIA EL REDICCIONAMIENTO A GOOGLE MAPS DONDE EN X , Y TENGO LAS COORDENADAS
            }
            ,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return barraiconos;
  }

  _launchURL() async {
    var url = 'tel: '+celular;
    print(celular);
    if (celular != null){
     if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }


    }else{
      AlertDialog(
        content: Text('No contiene numero telefonico'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el mismo paquete `url_launcher` por ejemplo:

**Para Facebook (es igual para cualquier URL):**

```
_launchURLToFacebook(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

**Para Google Maps:**
Según la [documentación de Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) la url puede ser así:

```
_launchURLToMaps(String latitud, String longitud) async {
  String url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitud,$longitud';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Invocar funcions:

```
//ACA IRIA EL REDICCIONAMIENTO A FACEBOOK DONDE TENGO EN EL STRING FACEBOOK TENGO LA URL
onTap: () => _launchURLToFacebook('https://facebook.com/FlutterPeru'),
//ACA IRIA EL REDICCIONAMIENTO A GOOGLE MAPS DONDE EN X , Y TENGO LAS COORDENADAS
onTap: () => _launchURLToMaps('-12.120886','-77.0301962'),
```